# Android ScrollView SearchBar

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to build a searchbar over a full screen image slider who can be scrolled.
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPQzP.png)
But when i am scrolling down, my logo and searchbar are scrolled too.
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdPFg.png)
How can i do to be fixed even i scroll down or not?
This is my xml file. I need that imageslider to be fullscreen when i open the activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider
                android:id="@+id/slider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:iss_auto_cycle="true"
                app:iss_corner_radius="5"
                app:iss_delay="0"
                app:iss_period="1000">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

                    <SearchView
                        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:autofillHints="@string/searchint"
                        android:background="@drawable/bg_round"
                        android:queryBackground="@color/transparent"
                        android:queryHint="SEARCH PRODUCTS"
                        android:theme="@style/SearchViewStyle" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/emaillogare"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:autofillHints="@string/email"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/email"
                    android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/logareparola"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:autofillHints="@string/parola"
                    android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/parola"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:buttonTint="@color/white"
                    android:paddingStart="30sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: do you need the viewpage to be fixed and the searchBar to be scrollable??

Comment: @KamalNayan yes

Answer (score 0):

Separate your search bar such that it resides *outside* of the ScrollView.

```
<ParentLayout>
    <LayoutContainingSearchBar>
        ---- Search Bar related items
    </LayoutContainingSearchBar>

    <SrollView>
        ---- Scrollable Area
    </SrollView>
</ParentLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below and if the problem persists, let me know.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
     <SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:autofillHints="@string/searchint"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_round"
                    android:queryBackground="@color/transparent"
                    android:queryHint="SEARCH PRODUCTS"
                    android:theme="@style/SearchViewStyle" />
     </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider
            android:id="@+id/slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:iss_auto_cycle="true"
            app:iss_corner_radius="5"
            app:iss_delay="0"
            app:iss_period="1000">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

             
            </LinearLayout>

        </com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emaillogare"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:autofillHints="@string/email"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/email"
                android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/logareparola"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:autofillHints="@string/parola"
                android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/parola"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:buttonTint="@color/white"
                android:paddingStart="30sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

 </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Feel free to ask if something is unclear.